# Video MMS from wap downloading as .qcp and .jpeg

Tags: android, mms, wap, pdu

I've sent a 3gp video as an MMS, testing the ability to download it from a WAP server. When I attempt to download it from the server it comes in as 2 separate parts. One part is a jpeg and the other is a qcp audio file. If I sent it to the WAP server as a 3gp file, why has it separated into two distinct MMS parts?

Is it possible that Android's MMS content provider detects the qcp file and combined it with the jpeg into the 3gp container format?

I've ripped apart every single line of code in the Android MMS app and there is no conversion going on whatsoever. All the MMS app does is download the pdu, separate the parts, and persist them to the MMS content provider as byte arrays. I can confidently say that the MMS app does not do anything with the parts, they are committed to the phones content provider as separate byte arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is specification of MMS, content adaptation.

The MMS server sent appropriate content to its receiver.

More precisely, 'appropriate' means the server's configuration and receiver's UA header decide  download content.

If there was no receiver's model in MMS server's DB, the server sent such configuration.
 If you fake UA header to supported model, the server should send 3gp video file.